# Print elements in list of tuple of tuple

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples of tuples:

```
countries = [(('germany', 'berlin'),3),(('england', 'london'),90),(('holland', 'amsterdam'), 43)]
```

I am trying to return all items that match a specific string. So far I have this:

```
for i in countries:
   if i[0] == 'germany':
      print i
```

This returns:

```
('germany', 'berlin')
```

My desired output would be:

```
('germany', 'berlin'),3)
```

I have looked at list comprehension in the documentation but I cannot work out how to show the number for each tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you are looking for is

```
for i in countries:
   if i[0][0] == 'germany':
      print i
```

Since you are a bit confused about the indexing:

```
i --> (('germany', 'berlin'),3)
i[0] --> ('germany,'berlin')
i[0][0] --> 'germany'
```

Comment: This works as expected - I thought this would be something like print i[0][0] can you explain why adding a second index into the if statement prints out the other tuple?

Answer (score 2):

If you're building that data structure yourself, I'd recommend you to use a more explicit structure, like a dict or a namedtuple.

With your data structure, what you need is:

```
countries = [(('germany', 'berlin'),3),(('england', 'london'),90),(('holland', 'amsterdam'), 43)]
for country in countries:
    if country[0][0]:
        print(country)
```

While with a dict, you could have:

```
countries = [{'id': 3,
              'info': {'name': 'germany',
                       'capital': 'berlin'}},
             {'id': 90,
              'info': {'name': 'england',
                       'capital': london}}]
for country in countries:
    if country['info']['name'] == 'germany':
        print(country)
```

Which I personally think it's much easier to read. [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) is probably a better structure in this case, but it's slightly more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

The current answer is sufficient, but if you want to check both items in the tuple for the string you could do this:

```
for i in countries:
    if 'germany' in i[0]:
        print i
```